# Dispatcher forward method from POST to GET

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, forward

I need to forward from my FooServlet **doPost** method to BarServlet **doGet** method. Is there a way to solve this?

Currently I'm calling the doGet method from my doPost but I'm sure that this isn't the best practice.

Comment: You fail to understand the meaning of HTTP methods. Please read our servlets wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming HTTP servlets intended for web-based use, I would recommend a `ServletResponse.sendRedirect(...)` to have the client request service from `BarServlet` in order to convey some insight into the server's view on things, and to avoid unintended re-POSTs, and so on.

Comment: You probably want to do a redirect "303 See Other" (see the HTTP spec, RFC1626).